# Unable to perform queries on mongodb started with --auth switch in rails 3 with mongoid. 

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid, mongohq

### Simplified case:

I create a new rails 3.2 project, without active record. I add mongoid 3.0.0.rc to the Gemfile and then `rails g mongoid:config`. I edit my `mongoid.yml` to look like the one I have posted below (except that hosts is now set to `localhost:27068`).

I have added an admin user to mongodb:

```
$ mongo localhost/admin
> db.addUser(myadmin,adminpass)
```

Also I have added a regular user to my database:

```
use mydb
> db.addUser(myuser, mypassword)
```

I confirm that I can connect to my database:

```
$ mongo localhost/mydb -u myuser -pmypassword
MongoDB shell version: 2.0.4
connecting to: localhost/mydb
> _
```

After that, I start `mongod` with `--auth` switch to force authentication:

```
$ mongod --auth --dbpath /my/db/path
```

Now that everything seems to be OK, I create some random scaffold like:

```
$ rails g scaffold User name email
```

and try to run the project in the browser: localhost:3000/users. BOOM! I'm hit with the error message posted below.

Is this a bug in mongoid? Or am I missing something?

---

### Original Question

I'm unable to do anything on my MongoHQ hosted database in a Rails 3.2 project with mongoid 3 rc. A simple query for login action gives me something like this error message:

```
The operation: #<Moped::Protocol::Query
  @length=83
  @request_id=3
  @response_to=0
  @op_code=2004
  @flags=[]
  @full_collection_name="mydb.users"
  @skip=0
  @limit=-1
  @selector={"name"=>"Abbas"}
  @fields=nil>
failed with error 10057: "unauthorized db:mydb lock type:-1 client [some ip]"
```

Here's what my `mongoid.yml` looks like:

```
development:
  sessions:
    default:
      database: mydb
      user: myuser
      password: mypassword
      hosts:
        - flame.mongohq.com:27068
      options:
        consistency: :strong
  options:
    include_type_for_serialization: true
```

So I'm doing it the wrong way. The db user is not marked as "Read-only" in MongoHQ panel. And I'm NOT deploying to Heroku; just testing on my localhost.

Any help is appreciated.